# PostgreSQL isn't using all available vCPUs of the VM

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

Running some procedures takes too much time and if I check `htop` I can see just one vCPU of the Ubuntu VM that is running and the others aren't:

[image]

#### postgresql.conf

```
max_connections = 50
shared_buffers = 2GB
max_prepared_transactions = 30
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix
max_worker_processes = 8
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 4
max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 4
max_parallel_workers = 7
max_wal_size = 8GB
min_wal_size = 2GB
effective_cache_size = 6GB
maintenance_work_mem = 512MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
work_mem = 10485kB
```

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. What is your actual question? Could you please [edit] your question and explain in detail what you are trying to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you expect Postgres to use more than one vCPU?